# how to make java application display chinese under fedora core 5

Tags: java, linux

we have a java application running under fedora core 5. the jdk version is 1.5. after installed the chinses/TrueType under the /usr/share/fonts the firefox can display chinese pages but the java application display nothing for those chinese unicode (\uXXXX). I modified the jre/lib/fontconfig.properties.src file to add a line of "appendedfontpath=/usr/share/fonts/chinese/TrueType". but still the same.

Anybody can help me with this?
thanks,

Answer (score 0):

What Java application? You'd have to tell that application to use whatever font you have in mind, using whatever configuration method the application provides.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you use the Chinese font to display the text. If you can't hardcode the font name, you can use the code in my answer to this question,

[Displaying Chinese text in an Applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754697/displaying-chinese-text-in-an-applet)

Answer (score 0):

remember to provide `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` argument when starting the VM.